# "Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 3.6.1" when not using system Protobuf library

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I am using CMake as a build tool and have pre-packaged binaries for all libraries I use in my project. One of those libraries is Protobuf and gets downloaded via Conan IO. So, I want to use the Protobuf downloaded by Conan and not the one already installed by Linux. The problem is that I get the following error when running `CMake`:

```
CMake Warning at /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 3.6.1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/username/Documents/project/test/script/cmake/Env.cmake:139 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)


-- Found Protobuf: /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/.conan/data/Protobuf/3.6.1/project/dev/package/80043e232e8ab07f4b25e67652a9490d9ad33d91/lib/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread (found version "3.6.1") 
CMake Warning at /home/username/Documents/project/test/build/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:455 (message):
  Protobuf compiler version doesn't match library version 3.6.1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/username/Documents/project/test/src/shared/bysp/CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)
```

Is there a way to fix this? Is this something that can cause errors?

Comment: You need to process your `.proto` files with `protoc` compiler built against the same protobuf library version that you are going to use at run time.

Comment: I ran into a similar message building a project on my Mac where I had several dependencies installed via Homebrew.  I reinstalled all my homebrew dependencies via `brew list --formula | xargs brew reinstall` and no longer got a version mismatch warning.

Answer (score 9):

I solved it in a Raspberry adding the next option to the CMake call.

```
 -D Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/protoc
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, the problem was that `cmake` couldn't actually find the correct path to my Protobuf compiler.

If you check CMake's *FindProtobuf.cmake* module (*/usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake*), the warning message happens here:

```
if(NOT "${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE_VERSION}" VERSION_EQUAL "${Protobuf_VERSION}")
   message(WARNING "Protobuf compiler version ${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE_VERSION}"
          " doesn't match library version ${Protobuf_VERSION}")
endif()
```

It's expected that the warning message will print out the actual Protobuf compiler version installed in your system. However, the actual version number is not part of the message.

In the *FindProtobuf.cmake* module, if you check some lines above when it tries to get the path to the Profobuf compiler, it does:

```
# Find the protoc Executable
find_program(Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE
    NAMES protoc
    DOC "The Google Protocol Buffers Compiler"
    PATHS
    ${Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER}/vsprojects/${_PROTOBUF_ARCH_DIR}Release
    ${Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER}/vsprojects/${_PROTOBUF_ARCH_DIR}Debug
)
```

There's no code later that checks whether a path could be found. The next step is executing the program and checking what's the version:

```
# Check Protobuf compiler version to be aligned with libraries version
execute_process(COMMAND ${Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE} --version
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE _PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE_VERSION)

if("${_PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE_VERSION}" MATCHES "libprotoc ([0-9.]+)")
  set(_PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE_VERSION "${CMAKE_MATCH_1}")
endif()
```

And since, at least it my system, there's no `protoc` program (but `protoc-c`), this check fails and that's also the reason why the warning message doesn't print a message for the actual version of the Protobuf compiler installed in the system.

The solution is to change the `find_program` statement to something like:

```
# Find the protoc Executable
find_program(Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE
    NAMES protoc-c protoc
    DOC "The Google Protocol Buffers Compiler"
    PATHS
    ${Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER}/vsprojects/${_PROTOBUF_ARCH_DIR}Release
    ${Protobuf_SRC_ROOT_FOLDER}/vsprojects/${_PROTOBUF_ARCH_DIR}Debug
)
```

And remove *CMakeCache.txt* and *CMakeFiles/* before rerunning `cmake`.

Comment: I learned it's possible to have `protoc-c` installed without `protoc`. So actually, I think a better solution is to install `protoc` (`apt-get install protobuf-compiler`).

Comment: The error message was a bug in the FindProtobuf module of CMake. The module fails through the wrong version condition when what is actually happening is that `protoc` could not be found. It will be fixed in a future release of CMake https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/4121

Comment: Am thankful. Installing protobuf-compiler first solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to install the compiler, on Ubuntu and Debian you should install the lib and the compiler as follows for C++:

```
sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your downloaded protoc can't start for some reason. Try to get protobuf version

```
./protoc --version
```

in corresponding dir.

Answer (score 0):

Based on arhuaco answer, its possible to use in cmake config:

```
set(Protobuf_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/protoc)
```